# Should I make modules_install install everytime I make a little change to linux kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, gnu-make

Should I make modules_install install everytime I make a little change to linux kernel ?

For example, If I want to print out the variable in fs/namei.c, the only thing I did was printk(...) should I make modules_install install after I make ?

Comment: No. you just need to make your kernel and need to update in your system (if your configurations are OK)

Comment: @JissJ thanks for the comment. How can I update in my system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the change is in the kernel and not in a kernel module, indeed there is no need to run "make modules_install". If for example the platform is x86_64, it is enough in the example you posted to run "make bzImage" and then "make install". And running "make bzImage" is faster than runnung "make", because when you run "make" you are also building the modules. However, if you changed something that can affect kernel modules, like a header file which they use, than you must run make, and then make modules_install and then make install, so that the change will take effect.

Rami Rosen